# How to use Averageifs to Calculate average with multiple criteria and ignore text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i want to calculate the average refer the contractor name and ignore the text "NA".
I know that it needs to use averageifs to calculate but it shows the #DIV/0! error if the data contain text or no text
Would you please tell me how to fix it?
I had wrote down my formula and the result in below
Thank you

[image]

Comment: #N/A usually refers when theres no data found. If Your Adequate safety measuers2 are getting pulled by VLOOKUP or somekind of other search, and there is no data to be found Your result will be #N/A. And because of this when You are doing Your AVERAGEIFS function it will result in a #DIV/0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Contractor is in "A1":

`=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$B$11;$A$2;$B$2:$B$11))`

(Maybe the ";" in my formula must be replaced by "," depending on your excel system.)

If there are "#N/A"s then make an ignore term in the formula:

`=AVERAGEIFS(table_range, criteria_range1, criteria, criteria_range2, "<>#N/A")`

`AVERGAGEIF(S)` and `SUMIF(S)` automatically ignore text/string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, it is not work and still show #DIV/0! Error

Comment: Click into your formula and mark separate parts of the formula an press "F9". What does it show? I also edited my answer, please try it again.

Comment: It still show "#DIV/0!", your formula is right after I try to copy the data to another sheet and delete 'NA".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the text or errored values (such as NA) are throwing errors inside of your AVERAGEIFS. If you put an IF inside of AVERAGE, it will go around this issue:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(Sheet1[Contractor]="AT",Sheet1[Adequate safety measures2]))
```

or

```
=AVERAGE(IF(Sheet1[Contractor]="TS-SP",Sheet1[Adequate safety measures2]))
```

**CORRECTED VERSION**

I realized that if the NA's are actually N/A errors, the above formula will result in NA, so here is the corrected version:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(Sheet1[Contractor]="AT",IFERROR(Sheet1[Adequate safety measures2],FALSE)))
```

which wraps the result in an iferror to convert it to FALSE so that it is not calculated.